# translate3d/translate doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, css, cordova

I have been trying to make simple CSS translate work on Android, but unable to. My code works perfectly on desktop chrome/safari. However when I am trying to run it on Android, I don't see any effect.

My div has following style:

```
.trans{
            position: absolute;
            font-size:100px;
            line-height:100px;
            text-align:center;
            top: 40px;
            left: 40px;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background:rgba(150,150,150, 0.5);
            opacity:0.5;
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
        }
```

On click I add the following style:

```
.trans.move {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 500px, 0px);
        }
```

I tried for translate and translateY also

Comment: If you add `translate3d(0px, 500px, 0px);` to `.trans{...}` does it work? It looks like the issue might be with your javascript.

Comment: Not exactly. The original trans class initializes the layer with 0 translation. And on a condition, I add .move to it.

Comment: I also found the answer. Android <3 doesnt have translate3d/translate support :(